# Como mapear uma propriedade de somente leitura no Fluent nhibernate, erro ao identificar setter

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Possuo uma propriedade que deve ser somente leitura, realizei mapeamento via código e atribui o parâmetro para somente leitura, porém, me apresenta uma exceção informando que não foi localizado o setter da propriedade

Execeção:`"Could not find a setter for property 'IndexValue 'in class ... "`

meu atributo IndexValue, que é onde ocorre a exceção está da seguinte maneira na classe.

```
public class MyClass: EntityBase
{
    .
    .
    .       
    public virtual decimal CropCode{ get; set ; }
    public virtual decimal UnityDiscount { get; set; }       
    public virtual decimal IndexValue { get; set; }
   }
```

onde também ja tentei remover o virtual e não obtive sucesso.

meu mapeamento foi feito da seguinte maneira:

```
public MapMyClass()
    {
        Table("MyTable");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(c => c.Code, "CODI_EMP")
            .KeyProperty(c => c.OrCode, "PEDI_PED")       
        Map(c => c.CropCode).Column("CODI_CUL");
        Map(c => c.UnityDiscount).Column("DSAC_IPE");
        .
        .
        Map(c => c.IndexValue).ReadOnly();
    }
```

Ja tentei realizar o mapeamento alterando também para:

```
 Map(c => c.IndexValue).Access.ReadOnly();
```

e também com

```
  Map(c => c.IndexValue).Access.Field();
```

O erro ocorre quando o nhibernate tenta executar a query, já executei a query diretamente no banco e ocorre tudo normal.

Comment: A propriedade `IndexValue` no banco na tabela `MyTable` a coluna de chama `IndexValue`?

Comment: Não pois o Indexvalue é passado como parâmetro para a consulta sql, não preciso dele no banco. Ja tentei criar a propriedade e nao mapea-la mas também não resolveu..

Comment: Se ele não está na base de dados e é apenas um campo de controle para a aplicação, então simplismente não o mapeie, pois não faz nenhum sentido querer mapear para o Nhibernate algo que nem na base de dados está, se você está vendo essa necessidade, com certeza você está fazendo algo muito errado.

Comment: Ele não estava mapeado, justamente por isso tentei mapea-lo e setar como ReadOnly afim de evitar a exceção onde informa que não localizou seu setter.

Comment: Mas você está utilizando esse atributo(`IndexValue`) em alguma Query do NHibernate? Pois se ele não está no banco de dados você não pode fazer Query com ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique a sua busca pode, ser que você tenha alguma tabela que esteja com o valor incorreto, todas as formas de mapeamento que você tentou utilizar estão corretas.

Em Oracle é necessário que você tenha o cuidado de colocar o nome de referencia das colunas iguais. Pode ser que um espaço venha a dar todo esse problema para você. No erro que você listou o nome do seu `'IndexValue'` está com espaço no final, se sua coluna não estiver com esse espaço, pode ser essa a causa do problema.

Comment: Realmente, o problema era o espaço, removie e funcionou perfeitamente na base oracle. Obrigado!